# Unity Framework resolve error

Tags: c#

I am getting an error when the UnityContainer.Resolve method runs which states...
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurreed in Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.dll.

Can anyone help me with where to start on troubleshooting this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have circular dependencies.

Comment: Yes. I by mistake added a dep injection into the same service class and this started happening. Removed the link and issue solved!